# FormData() missing some data

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I have HTML form (having user picture & data) I am submitting it using following code. Problem is that, it sometimes submits all data & picture file but sometimes it misses some input text fields data. For examples, sometimes username is not submitted in data.

```
$("button#btn-save").click(function(){
    fd = new FormData;
    $.each($('#user-form').serializeObject(), function(key, val){
        fd.append(key, val);
    });
    pic = $("input[name=pic]")[0].files[0];
    fd.append('pic', pic);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'employee/save-new-employee',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false
        data: fd,
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
            //somecode
        }, 
        error: function(d){
            //errorhandling
        }
    });
});
```

Here is serializeObject function:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
}
```

Comment: `new FormData` -> `new FormData()`

Comment: `fd = new FormData();`

Comment: Also note that your `serializeObject` function is completely pointless. You're looping through the form inputs once due to `serializeArray()`, then again in `serializeObject()`, then again in your click handler. Just do `new FormData($('#user-form')[0])`. It will have the exact same output

Comment: thanks for pointing Rory'